# How to draw a rectangle using specific cordinates, that we get from backend/API?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In the backgroud I have image, here I need to draw a rectangle using specific coordinates (they come from API) on a image. 
 How to draw dynamically because coordinates keep changing.

I have tried using canvas, svg but dind't work. Link for previous question
[How to draw svg on image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083440/how-to-draw-svg-on-image)

cordinates:

```
        var a = _self.sendObjCoordinates[0].coordinates.xmin;
        var b = _self.sendObjCoordinates[0].coordinates.ymin;
        var c = _self.sendObjCoordinates[0].coordinates.xmax;
        var d  = _self.sendObjCoordinates[0].coordinates.ymax;
```

sample values:

```
     {xmin: 399, ymin: 191, xmax: 1166, ymax: 742}
```

1)code for loading image:

```
<div class="lbi-svg-box scrollbar-external">
    <img src=""  alt="" class="lbi-img"  />
    <svg class="lbi-svg">
    </svg>  
</div>
```

2)Here i am creating canvas

```
Labelimg.prototype = {
        addImg: function (src) {
            var img = document.querySelector('.lbi-img');
            if (!img) {

                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                img = document.createElement('img');
                img.className = 'lbi-img';
                canvas.id = "CursorLayer";
                canvas.width = 500;
                canvas.height = 700;
            }
         }
     }

The error is :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.submitFormBtn.onclick (labelimg.js:418)
```

3)Code for creating rect:

```
var can = document.getElementById("CursorLayer");

                var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
                ctx.fillStyle='#fa4b2a';    // color of fill
                ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
                ctx.stroke(); // create rectangle
```

Comment: “It didn’t work” is not diagnostic. What didn’t work?

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? Share your code

Comment: Show us the code where you're trying to draw that data onto the canvas.

Comment: @Madhu@obscure please have a look at updated code.

Comment: @DaveNewton please instruct me.

Answer (score 0):

The time you're trying to draw the rectangle onto the canvas your utilizing
the **getElementyById()** function to get a reference to your canvas.
Unfortunately it will return *null* because you didn't actually add the canvas to the DOM - thus it doesn't exist and you're getting:

> Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Adding a dynamically created HTML element to the DOM is done by the **appendChild()** function.

Try changing:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
```

to:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```